# Indicate continuance in wireframe

Tags: wireframe

I'm currently wire-framing a mobile app which has multiple question across 3 categories. I want to show in my wire-framing tool that the questions in each category are a sub-set for example purposes.

Would a couple of faded images do it?

[image: Fading Images Example]

Or a continuation brace?

[image: Continuation Brace]

are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Are `Safety` and `Quality` categories? If so, what's the third category?

Comment: There is a third - Environmental.

Comment: If that's Balsamiq there's a 'breakline' option if you use a canvas or geometric shape symbol. That makes it quite clear that you've cut the wireframe deliberately and makes it clear that it's not part of the actual interface.

Comment: Prototype it and avoid this all together.

Answer (score 1):

I used to spend a lot of time pasting in page-tear images, masking and aligning screen tops and screen bottoms in wireframes. But that's not the point of wireframes. The point is to communicate clearly.

The fade you have in the first image would serve well with a little annotation, e.g., "continued on next page ...."

Answer (score 1):

I usually bracketed text to indicate variables or 'etcetera' siuations:

```
1. Access Egress
2. Accidents/Book
3. [additional questions...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Biggest thing is about consistency in the way you represent it. You probably want to put in an annotation on the first page indicating the expected behaviour if it'll be viewed by people who are unfamiliar with your work.

If the interface is expected to scroll to show more data, I cut off the last row so only portion of text is visible. Like your faded image example, but without the fading.

If no in section scrolling is required, then I put "..." as the title of the last row to indicate display more rows as needed.